# Asynchronously exit loop via interupt or similar (MSP430/C)

Tags: c, loops, exit, msp430, isr

I have run into a problem that I am rather stumped on because every solution I can think of has an issue that makes it not work fully. I am working on a game on the MSP430FF529 that when first powered up has two images drawn to the screen infinitely using a loop and cycle delays. I would like to have it so that when the user presses the start button (a simple high-edge trigger on a port) that the program immediately stops drawing those screens, no matter what part of the process its in, and starts executing the rest of the code that runs the game.

I could put the function that puts the images on screen in a do while loop but then it wouldn't be asynchronous as the current image being drawn would have to finish before it moved on.

I'd use the break command but I don't think that works in ISRs and only when its directly in the loop.

I could put the entire rest of the program in the ISR I use for the start button press so that the screen drawing is essentially never returned to but thats really messes, poor coding, and would cause a lot of problems later.

Essentially, I want to make it so that when the button is pressed the program will immediately jump to the part of the program that is the actual game and forget about drawing those images on the screen. Is it possible to somehow have an ISR that doesn't return to what was currently happening after the code in the routine is executed? Basically, once the program starts moving forward (the start button is pressed) I don't want to come back to the function that draws the images unless I explicitly call it again.

The only thing I can think of is the goto command, which I feel in this particular instance would not actually be too bad, though I want to avoid using it for fear of it becoming a habit due to it being a poor solution in most cases. However, that might not even work because I have a feeling that using goto in a ISR would really mess up the stack.

Any ideas? Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: You could use an RTOS of some sort.  Set the game thread at a higher priority than the rendering threads, but hang it on a semaphore.  Set the semaphore in the interrupt handler and exit the handler to the scheduler.  That will switch to the game as soon as the interrupt is over.

Comment: The question is far too broad for a good answer. Sure you can jump where you want using assembler, etc. But that is beyond the C language. C does not even have a concept of hardware interrupts for a freestandaing environment. Alternatively you can set a flag from the interrupt handler you test in the main code. Note: mechanical buttons will bounce. You have to take measures against detecting multiple pulses for a single keypress.

Comment: `goto` is only allowed inside a single function. And in general it is bad style to wildly jump in your code. Be assured, if not instantly, it will eventually cause trouble later.

Comment: Main loop: `if(start_button_pressed) break;` ISR: `start_button_pressed = 1;`

Answer (score 1):

What you want is basically a "context switch". You should modify the program counter pointer and stack pointer which will be restored when you return from the ISR, and then do the normal ISR return so the interrupt mask is cleared, stack is restored, etc. As noted in the comments to your question, this likely requires some manual assembly code.

I'm not familiar with the MSP430, but on other architectures this is in a structure of saved registers on the kernel stack or interrupt-context stack (or maybe just "the stack" on some microcontrollers), or it might be in some special registers, and it's saved automatically by the CPU when it jumps to your ISR. So you have to change these register pointers where they are.

Comment: I had a feeling it might require some assembly. I will look into it. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

If you relax your requirement from "immediately" to "so fast that the user doesn't notice", you can put the `if (button_pressed)` into some loop in the image drawing routine.

---

If you really want to abort the image drawing immediately, you can do so by resetting the MCU (for example, by writing a wrong password to the WDT). In the application initialization code, check if one of the causes of the reset was your own software:

```
bool start_button = false;
for (;;) {
    int cause = SYSRSTIV;
    if (cause == SYSRSTIV_WDTKEY)
        start_button = true;
    if (cause == SYSRSTIV_NONE)
        break;
    // you might handle debugging of other reset causes here ...
}
if (!start_button)
    draw_images();
else
    actual_game();
```

(This assumes that your code never accidentally writes a wrong WDT password, but even if that happens, you're only skipping the intro images.)

Comment: Wow that second option is an interesting solution that I might give a shot. I am currently trying what you said as the first option by using a couple conditional statements during each part of the intro draw, but having issues with the interrupt. I have no problems with any of my interrupts occurring once main is finished and I run "_BIS_SR(LPM4_bits + GIE);" to enable low power mode and interrupts, but since I need this interrupt to happen before main is finished and before low power mode is activated I tried just "_BIS_SR(GIE);" earlier on. (CHECK NEXT COMMENT)

Comment: While doing this the program still runs through in the debugger but nothing appears on the screen so it looks like it somehow messes up the PORT I/O. Not really sure why.